# Adobe Acrobat Pro DC PDF Submit Button To ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApplication Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf

In my PDF I have a submit button that in theory should submit the PDF document to my Controller.
Once the Submit button is pressed, when I debug, I can see in UploadPDF that List files has a file count of 0.  How do I get the PDF to send the file to my controller? Am I making the wrong assumption that this can be done? Or should I use Javascript to do this? (What would the Javascript look like?)

[image]

[image]

```
    [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPDF(List<IFormFile> files)
    {


        //
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var x = file.FileName;
            var y = file.ContentType;
            var strExtension = "application/pdf";
            //if (!strExtension.Contains("pdf"))
            //{
            //    ModelState.AddModelError("myErrorFileName", "Please enter a PDF file. (.pdf)");
            //}
            if (file.Length == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("myErrorFileName", "The file is empty and has a length of zero.");
            }
        }


        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            //Start the File List
            List<string> records = new List<string>();

                //Read fileStream
                using (var fileStream = item.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                 //Do more stuff

            }
            }

        //return
        return View();




    }
```

Comment: What are you using to fill/submit the form.  Any "off brand" pdf viewer might not support some of the less used features ("submit entire PDF", JS, etc).  I'm not aware of any pdf client other than Adobe Reader that supports javascript.

Comment: By the way, there's an actual "Submit Form" action you can use rather than the "Execute menu item->submit form" you're using now.  That *shouldn't* matter, but it might.